# Remove whitespace from number within text in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have text like this format

> "term: 156^^^:^^59 datainput" Or "term: 156^^^:59 datainput" or "term: 156:^^^59"

The "^" represented white space.
Notice the white space between the the two numbers and the colon. There 2, 3, 4 or even 7 white space between the two number. I want to remove these white space so that the text can be in this format :

> > "term: 156:59 datainput"

which is no more space between the the two number -> 156:56. I want to remove the white space between the number and the colon only.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
Dim result = Regex.Replace(input, "(\d)\s*:\s*(\d)", "$1:$2")
```

This uses a regular expression to match the spaces in between the numbers and the colons.  Any pattern such as this will be replaced with the last argument.  The $1 and $2 are escape sequences which say "replace with text matched by the first and second parenthesis". In this case it will be a single digit.

Comment: @Jose, they rock until you have to maintain a 4 line regex the guy before you wrote ;)

Comment: Often a developer has a problem and thinks "I know, I'll use regular expressions", now he has two problems...

Comment: @balabaster, absolutely true. Unforutanately most people don't realize the inherit limitations of regex's and as a result attempt to use them for problems they cannot possibly solve. Results in a lot of wasted time.  QA loves this though because it inevitable leads to a bug farm :)

Answer (score 1):

I think regex will help handle the different number of whitespace characaters.

```
    Dim text As String = "term: 156      :     59 datainput "
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "([0-9])\s*:\s*([0-9])", "$1:$2", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Comment: Different regex. Same result. +1